# Form serialize for an array in a form

Tags: php, forms, serialization

Ok, I know there were a lot of questions on this issue, but I still can't understand how to use it.

I have a form with fields with the same name, so the field looks like that:

```
<input type="text" name="products[]" />
```

My ajax call looks like this:

```
var products = $('#orderDetsForm').serialize();
    eve.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/orders/index.php/processOrder/addOrderDets",
     data: {dets: products},
     success: function(data){
   $("#productList").html(data);
```

When I print the products to the page I get this:

products%5B%5D=5products%5B%5D=7

How do I get the values in the php file?

And is there a way for me to get the fileds id's, since each id is actually the product's id, that I need to insert into a table.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

You could give each input a unique name, containing the product ID. That way you kill two birds with one stone - easy access to IDs, and no worrying about duplicates.

You can access POST params in PHP by using  $_POST predefined variable.

Comment: That's a good idea, but how will I send it to the php file with ajax?

Comment: Maybe I should mention I am using codeigniter.
So I tried: $products = $this->input->post('products1');    

And I've tried that:    $products = $_POST['products1'];    
but I get the error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: products1

Filename: controllers/processOrder.php

Line Number: 99